# Proving that $(A \cup B) \times (C \cap D) = ((A \times C) \cap (A \times D)) \cup ((B \times C) \cap (B \times D))$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help proving this $$(A \cup B) \times (C \cap D) = ((A \times C) \cap (A \times D)) \cup ((B \times C) \cap (B  \times D))$$

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: Compare the definitions of $A \times (C \cap D)$ and $(A \times C) \cap (A \times D)$ (hint: they are the same). Then do the same thing with $B$ and conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it.

If $(m,n) \in (A\cup B)\times (C\cap D)$ then $m \in A\cup B$ (or $m \in A$ or $m\in B$)  and $n\in C\cap$ (or $n \in C$ and $n \in D$).

If $m\in A$ then $(m,n)\in A\times C$ and $(m,n)\in A\times D$ so $(m,n) \in (A\times C)\cap (A\times D)$.

Likewise if $m \in B$ then $(m,n)\in B\times C$ and $(m,n)\in B\times D$ so $(m,n) \in (B\times C)\cap (B\times D)$.

It's one or the other so $(m,n) \in ((A\times C)\cap (A\times D)) \cup  ((B\times C)\cap (B\times D))$.

So $(A\cup B)\times (C\cap D) \subset ((A\times C)\cap (A\times D)) \cup  ((B\times C)\cap (B\times D))$

On the other hand if $(m,n) \in  ((A\times C)\cap (A\times D)) \cup  ((B\times C)\cap (B\times D))$ then

either  $(m,n) \in (A\times C)\cap (A\times D)$ or $(m,n) \in (B\times C)\cap (B\times D)$.

if $(m,n) \in (A\times C)\cap (A\times D)$ then $m\in A$ and $n \in C$ and $n\in D$.

if $(m,n) \in (B\times C)\cap (B\times D)$ then $m \in B$ and $n \in C$ and $n \in D$.

So $m \in A$ or $m\in B$ so $m \in (A\cup B)$.  And $n \in C $ and $n \in D$ so $m \in (C\cap D)$.

So $(m,n) \in (A\cup b) \times (C\cap D)$

And so $((A\times C)\cap (A\times D)) \cup  ((B\times C)\cap (B\times D))\subset (A\cup B)\times (C\cap D)$

So $((A\times C)\cap (A\times D)) \cup ((B\times C)\cap (B\times D))= (A\cup B)\times (C\cap D)$

=====

Or you could do it by definition.

$((A\times C)\cap (A\times D)) \cup ((B\times C)\cap (B\times D))=$

$\{(m,n)|(m,n)\in (A\times C)\cap (A\times D)\text{ OR } (m,n)\in (B\times C)\cap (B\times D)\} =$

$\{(m,n)|[(m,n)\in A\times C \text{ and } (m,n)\in A\times D] \text{ OR }[(m,n) \in B\times C \text{ and } (m,n)\in B\times D]\}=$

$\{(m,n)|[m\in A;n\in C\text{ and } m\in A;n\in D] \text{ OR }[m\in B;n\in C \text{ and } m\in B;n\in D]\}=$

$\{(m,n)|[m\in A;n\in C;n\in D] \text{ OR }[m\in B;n\in C ;n\in D]\}=$

$\{(m,n)|m\in A\text{ or }m\in B; n\in C \text{ and } n\in D\}=$

$\{(m,n)|m \in A\cup B; n \in C\cap D\}=$

$(A\cup B) \times (C\cap D)$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. $(X\cup Y)\times Z=(X\times Z)\cup(Y\times Z)$
2. $X\times(Y\cap Z)=(X\times Y)\cap(X\times Z)$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(x,y) \in (A \cup B) \times (C \cap D).$ Then $x \in A \cup B$ and $y \in C \cap D.$ So either $x \in A$ or $x \in B.$ Suppose $x \in A.$ Then since $y \in C \cap D$ so we have $$(x,y) \in (A \times C) \cap (A \times D).$$  Otherwise if $x \in B$ then similarly we have $$(x,y) \in  (B \times C) \cap (B \times D).$$ So either $(x,y) \in  (A \times C) \cap (A \times D)$ or $(x,y) \in  (B \times C) \cap (B \times D).$ Therefore $$(x,y) \in  ((A \times C) \cap (A \times D)) \cup  ((B \times C) \cap (B \times D)).$$ So we get

$$(A \cup B) \times (C \cap D) \subseteq ((A \times C) \cap (A \times D)) \cup  ((B \times C) \cap (B \times D)).$$

Can you prove the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

So we need to show: $$(A \cup B) \times (C \cap D) = ((A \times C) \cap (A \times D)) \cup ((B \times C) \cap (B  \times D))$$.

According to the hints:

$$(A \cup B) \times (C \cap D)=(A \times (C \cap D) )\cup (B\times (C \cap D) ) = ((A \times C) \cap (A \times D)) \cup( (B \times C) \cap (B \times D))$$